# Merge [localization] and [language] tags

Tags: support, retag-request, tag-synonyms

[language](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language) is being used as a subset/synonym of [localization](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/localization), so they should be merged. Even though [language](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language) has more threads, I suggest using [localization](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/localization) as its parent since it has a more general meaning of adapting a web app to a foreign demographic.

Note: threads about languages themselves are being categorized as [language-learning](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language-learning), so this won't affect them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The merge is now complete. [localization](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/localization) is the parent tag.

Comment: Thank you. How to make a tag appear with special formatting like you did on your reply?

Comment: `[tag:"nameoftag"]` no quotations (") @screener